# If the distribution of $X+Y$ is discrete then both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete as well

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

"If the distribution of $X+Y$ is discrete then both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete as well"

I think this is true but I'm not sure how to go about proving it. I thought about using characteristic functions but I only know that since $X+Y$ is discrete, we must have $|\varphi_{X+Y}(t)|\leq 1$. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you maybe want X and Y to be independent? Otherwise this is not true in general, as the answer by Gandalf Sauron shows.

Comment: @PhoemueX Nah no independence. I'm just not too good at coming up with counterexamples... Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about when $X$ is a continuous distribution and $Y=-X$ or $Y=-X+1$. Then the rv $X+Y$ takes all it's value in the countable set $\{1\}$ with probability $1$.